# If this kind of redirection possible with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Lets say I had file on my website on this path

www.mysite.com/blah/images/picture.jpg

and then I transferred it to other website like this

www.my2ndsite.com/mysite/images/picture.jpg

can we redirect visitors to get image from www.my2ndsite.com while they visit www.mysite.com

Also if there is any command which first checks that if there at www.mysite.com that "picture.jpg" file exists. If its true then it just doesn't redirect visitors to www.my2ndsite.com .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do both with rewriting (put this in the htaccess in `www.mysite.com/` ) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blah/images/(.+\.jpg)$ http://www.my2ndsite.com/mysite/images/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request for some file in `http://www.mysite.com/blah/images/` that does not exists to `http://www.my2ndsite.com/mysite/images/`

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to an absolute URL: [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Checking if file exists: [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)